# Regex: Match a condition, then find the first occurrence of another condition that precedes it on the same line. Possible?

Tags: regex, find, sublimetext2, replace

Using Regular Expressions, I am looking to find a piece of text based on condition A, then look backwards from the found point and match condition B and replace the text of condition A with B's text.

For example:

The line

```
<div class='fourcol'><h2>REPLACE WITH THIS</h2><a class='abc' rel='1_1' id='def' href='#'><img src='imgs/abc.png' alt='<?= $_GET['event'] ?> t-shirt <?= $_GET['type'] ?> REPLACE THIS TEXT'/></a></div>
```

Searching for `REPLACE THIS TEXT` then looking backwards, getting the value between the first found `<h2>*.</h2>` occurrence, which is `REPLACE WITH THIS`, and replacing `REPLACE THIS TEXT` with it.

Is this possible using a text editors find replace regex function? I am using Sublime Text 2 in this case.

Comment: It is possible - gimme a tick... I may be too slow!

Comment: no experience with sublimetext2. if sublimetext2 supports group reference, it is a simple submatch substitution case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find using this:

```
(<h2>)(.*)(</h2>.*)(REPLACE THIS TEXT)
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2$3$2
```

If this pattern is not what you wanted then please clarify.

Cheers.

Comment: Nice one, will try now and let you know. Cheers

Comment: Spot on. Very, very nice. Cheers again

Comment: No worries bro. No worries at all

Comment: By the way, don't be afraid of that tick button!

Comment: You have actually saved me about 2 hours too!

Comment: Excellent! - and my strange love of regex got fed. it's a good day all round

Comment: She is a strange, yet alluring beast.

Comment: Yes she is. Damn she is sexy